# How to drop the first element in an array and use it as the initial value of the reduce function in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example instead of :

```
var c = [0, 1, 2, 3]

var c0 = c[0]

dropFirst(c).reduce( c0 + 5 ) { $0 * $1 }
```

Could the same be done without having to having to store c[0]?

I am looking for a one line statement

Comment: write your own extension method. and what is the result for empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dropFirst` does not mutate the state of c, so there is no need to store `c[0]`.

```
var c = [0, 1, 2, 3]

var c0 = c[0]

let a = dropFirst(c).reduce( c0 + 5 ) { $0 * $1 }

let b = dropFirst(c).reduce( c[0] + 5 ) { $0 * $1 }

a == b # True
```

Comment: Good to know :) thank you, that's the answer I was looking for